# JSONSerialization serialize dictionary with wrong types

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, jsonencoder

I'm having trouble translating my models into dictionaries.
My models inherit from Codable and when using JSONSerialization I get a dictionary with the form:

```
(...,"sensors": <__NSArrayI 0x1105324f0>( {
accx = "-0.002471923828125";
accy = "0.011444091796875";
accz = "-1.013595581054688";
gyrox = "-0.029818882093399213";
gyroy = "0.028939506301455049";
gyroz = "0.0044943506556177227"; }, ...)
```

(Note that my keys are not as string but the values are)

when in fact a want this:

```
(..., "sensors": [ {
"accx" = -0.002471923828125;
"accy" = 0.011444091796875;
"accz" = -1.013595581054688;
"gyrox" = -0.029818882093399213;
"gyroy" = 0.028939506301455049;
"gyroz" = 0.0044943506556177227;} ], ... )
```

My models are:

```
class Event: NSObject, Codable {

var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?
var speed: Double?
var date: String?
var type: String?
var sensors: [Sensor] = []

}

class Sensor: NSObject, Codable {
   var accx: Double?
   var accy: Double?
   var accz: Double?
   var gyrox: Double?
   var gyroy: Double?
  var gyroz: Double?
}
```

Im using this to transform into dictionary:

```
extension Encodable {

var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    do{

        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(self) else { return nil }
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        print(json)
        return json
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

I'm stuck with this and I do not know if I'm going down the right path.
Should I change the way I organize this dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the result of `NSDictionary.description` there, and the result of `NSDictionary.description` is **not** JSON and not necessarily an accurate representation of the contained objects.

There is no actual problem with the decoding. Example:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let json = "{ \"sensors\": [ { \"accx\": 0.011444091796875 } ] }"
json: String = "{ \"sensors\": [ { \"accx\": 0.011444091796875 } ] }"
  3> let d = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String: Any] 
d: [String : Any] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "sensors"
    value = {
      payload_data_0 = 0x0000000100111ad0
      payload_data_1 = 0x0000000000000000
      payload_data_2 = 0x0000000000000000
      instance_type = 0x00000001014179c8 libswiftCore.dylib`InitialAllocationPool + 4888
    }
  }
}
```

When we print the dictionary returned by `JSONSerialization`, we see the number in quotes:

```
  4> print(d)
["sensors": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x100111ad0>(
{
    accx = "0.011444091796875";
}
)
]
```

But when we actually extract the number from the nested containers, it is actually a `Double`:

```
  5> ((d["sensors"] as! [Any])[0] as! [String: Any])["accx"] as! Double
$R0: Double = 0.011444091796875
```

The moral of the story: **Don't expect an object's `description` to be an accurate serialization of its value.** If you need an accurate serialization, convert the object to JSON or a property list, or inspect it in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks man. I was in doubt because webservice returns code 500, I was thinking that the error was because my JSON parser